# Регулярное выражение для телефона в интернацианальном формате

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день, коллеги, требуется написать reg exp для проверки телефона на сервере. 
На фронте есть плагин, который позволяет вводить телефон, выбирая страну, прикрутил так же маску ввода maskedinput.js.

Хотел бы проверять, нету ли букв или превышения длины ещё и на бэке на php.

Условия следующие: телефон начинается с "+" или цифры (0-9), в телефоне всего от 8 до 20 символов 0-9, " ", "-", "(", ")". Более точной валидации на сервере не труебуется, в бд телефон не грузится.

Я не очень силен в регулярках, написал вот такое выражение, которое ведет себя не так как я предполагал:

```
/(\+){0,1}([\s\-\(\)0-9]){7,20}/
```

Посоветуйте подходящее выражение или исправьте ошибку в моем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день.
Попробуйте вот так:

```
^\+?[\s\-\(\)0-9]{7,19}$
```

Проверить можно [тут](https://regex101.com/r/mVn0O2/1)

Comment: Подходит, но нужен в конце $, иначе если продолжить строку, то по match все равно проходит.

Comment: Хорошо, добавил. :)

Comment: Огромное спасибо, очень помогло.